# How to display Activity Indicator until the data loads in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, uitableview

I am loading data into the `UITableView` from three WebServices in `ViewDidLoad` method. It is fine when the data from the webservices return soon, but when WebServices return null, the `UITableView` is loaded with empty rows. I want to display `UIActivityIndicator` until the `UITableView` is loaded and if the WebService return NULL value then the `UITableView` should not be displayed, instead it should display a pop-up.

Thanks in advance.....

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

     UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     [indicator startAnimating];
     indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
     [indicator sizeToFit];
     .......
     .......
     ....... 

     //code to read data from WebServices
     [indicator stopAnimating];

}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem that you are trying to fix (except that there's no code shown of displaying the `indicator` and `stopAnimating` seems to be called immediately) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code but I am giving example you should modify it & use according to your need:

```
alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];

                UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

                indicator.center = CGPointMake(150, 100);
                [indicator startAnimating];
                [alert addSubview:indicator];
```

Use this line to dismiss indicator:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Try. Best of luck.